# trying to connect two pug files but not able to do that

Tags: pugjs

I am trying to link two pug files but not able to do that and I am using koajs and mongodb

```
input(type='button', onclick="abc.pug", value='click here')
```

So can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? Navigating to another page?

Comment: What exactly is this onclick to another file meant to do?

Comment: actually am try to make a server using koa.js and in my pug file am trying to make link that on clicking it open up the html file.

Comment: but when I click on the link it show not found error. both html and pug file is in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't link to another Pug file. You would link to the HTML file that the desired Pug file compiles to. In your case, you need to link to `abc.html` instead of `abc.pug`.

EDIT: You're using the `onclick` attribute for the button, instead of using an anchor tag to create a link to another page. You need to use an `a` tag to link to another page, not a `button`.

```
<a href="abc.html">Click here</a>
```

`onclick` is reserved for running a JavaScript function when the button is clicked. If you need to make it a button *and* link to something, use CSS to visually style the anchor as if it were a button (e.g. `class="button"`).

Comment: See the edit I made to the post, you're not using `onclick` right.